# Adding child to specific header of ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-adapter

I am developing an app that use to ExpandableListview. Firstly I am adding headers and then I am adding childs to specific headers. But when I add childs , every header of ExpandableListView updating. (Screenshots explaining)

I use BaseExpandableListView adapter but not afford to solve this issue. Any help very worthy for me. Thank you

**Here my Adapter Class;**

```
public class SYCriteraAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<SYCriteraModel> mParent;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<SYCriteraModel>> mChild;
private View view;


public ArrayList<SYCriteraModel> getMParent() {
    return mParent;
}


public SYCriteraAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<SYCriteraModel> parentList) {
    this.mParent = parentList;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

}

public SYCriteraAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<SYCriteraModel> parentList,ArrayList<ArrayList<SYCriteraModel>> childList) {
    this.mParent = parentList;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mChild = childList;

}

// counts the number of group/parent items so the list knows how many
// times calls getGroupView() method
public int getGroupCount() {
    return mParent.size();
}

// counts the number of children items so the list knows how many times
// calls getChildView() method
public int getChildrenCount(int parentPosition) {
    int childCount = 0;
    try {
        childCount = mChild.get(parentPosition).size();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception " + e);
    }
    return childCount;
}

// gets the title of each parent/group
public Object getGroup(int i) {
    return null;
}

// gets the name of each item
public Object getChild(int parentPosition, int childPosition) {

    return null;
}

public long getGroupId(int parentPosition) {
    return 0;
}

public long getChildId(int i, int childPosition) {
    return 0;
}

public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

// in this method you must set the text to see the parent/group on the list

public View getGroupView(int parentPosition, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.critera_upper_adapter, viewGroup, false);
    }
    TextView uppercritera = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.etCritera);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    uppercritera.setText(mParent.get(parentPosition).getParent());
    return view;

}

// in this method you must set the text to see the children on the list

public View getChildView(int parentPosition, int childPosition, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.critera_lower_adapter, viewGroup, false);
    }
    TextView lowerCritera = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.etCritera);
    lowerCritera.setText(mChild.get(parentPosition).get(childPosition).getChildren());

    return view;
}

public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
    return true;
}


}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is one method getChildView  inside your BaseExpandable Adapter check parent position in that method .

```
public View getChildView(int parentPosition, int childPosition, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
if (view == null) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.critera_lower_adapter, viewGroup, false);
}
```

//Here You have to check position of parentPosition child should have added or not i,e

if(parentPosition==1 || parentPosition==3 || parentPosition==5)

```
    TextView lowerCritera = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.etCritera);
lowerCritera.setText(mChild.get(parentPosition).get(childPosition).getChildren());

return view;
```

Comment: But I dont know parent position sometimes. Assume that I defined parent position 5 and I only have 3 parent ? How can I gain flexibility to this piece of code ?

Comment: if you dont know the position of parent than how specifically set the child? ok don't be confused check the parent i mean header text if its match than only add the child.

Comment: I know parent position but It changable. I refer its changability.

Comment: Not sure but for reference you can try this  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15348971/3514144

Comment: By default your parentview is showing right? so you can set logic as like when parent in your case header is clicked http://stackoverflow.com/a/33359328/3514144 get position and make child  gone so your problem of changeability on scrolling will also gone

Answer (score 1):

try this by setting clicklistener

```
   expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,headers.get(groupPosition)+"--"+headeritems.get(headers.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

for more details refer here https://coderzpassion.com/android-expandable-listview-tutorial/

Comment: I am using setOnGroupClickListener to add childs on ExpandableListView.